# Pass data from JS to Python via Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to send data from python to JS in Django. I successfully see the data in the response in the browser, but JS returns as empty string. What would be the reason?

trying to fetch information;

```
def XXX(request):
    message_id=request.POST.get('messageid')
    return render(request, 'XX.html')
```

sender;

```
    y = json.loads(response.text)
    ts = str(y["file"]["shares"]["public"]["XX"][0]["ts"])
    return render (request, 'problemduyurusucreate.html', {'ts':ts})
```

JS;

```
    <script type=text/javascript>
    function slacksil() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("main"), {
    letterRendering: 1,
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,})
  .then(function (canvas) {
  swal({
    title: "Emin misiniz?",
    text: "Duyuru Kanaldan Silinecek!",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,})
  .then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
    document.getElementById("result").src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.5);
    var deneme = "{{ ts }}";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'slacksilproblem' %}",
    data: { 
    "messageid": deneme,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}})
  swal({
    title: "Duyuru Kanaldan Silindi!",
      icon: "success",})} 
  else {
  swal("İşlem İptal Edildi!", {
    icon: "error",});}});
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            alert(e);
        }); 
}
  </script>
```

but I am displaying in my browser that I have successfully pulled the data
[image]

first im sending post request to python for sending image after python script python send to html message timestamp id;
[image]

then post requst to delete message with timestamp id, but its comes empty to python. But when I look at the answer in the browser, I see that the data is coming
[image]

Comment: You have not attached any callbacks like `.done()` or `fail()`.

Comment: Actually, I think that issue is not a problem because when I look at the response of the request in the browser, I can see the data coming in the above way, but when I resend the data in a variable with ajax, it comes empty string.

Comment: Show us the full AJAX request and response preferably as code-formatted text.

Comment: i have updated the post

Comment: Since you aren't showing us the names of any of these routines, perhaps you should describe the whole path to where it's going wrong.  The image shows stuff filled in by the original request, but has nothing about the AJAX request.

Comment: updated the topic with detailed screenshots

Comment: Have you tried `"messageid": "{{ ts }}"` without using the variable?  Also where is the code that handles the request and returns the response of `'message_not_found'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by sending the data to the cookie with python and retrieving the data from again python.

sender data to cookie ( x is my data );

```
    html = HttpResponse("<h1>TP</h1>")
    html.set_cookie('ts', x, max_age = None)
    return html
```

and fetch data in another fonc. like this;

```
message_id=request.COOKIES['ts']
```

finally delete cookie;

```
html.delete_cookie('ts','!')
```